# Merge two csvs and convert to json using python

Tags: python, json, csv

I have two csv file

```
x.csv
================
A   B   D
1   b1  d1
2   b2  d2
3   b3  d3
4   b4  d4

y.csv
===================
A   B   D
1   1b  1d
2   2b  2d
3   3b  3d
5   5b  5d
====================
```

Here column a is id column.
I need  a json after mergeing this two file....
The data will look like

```
[{
   "A":1,
   "B":{ "x" :b1,
         "y" : 1b
      }
    "D" :{
         "x" :d1,
         "y" :1d
     }
  },{
   "A":2,
   "B":{ "x" :b2,
         "y" : 2b
      }
    "D" :{
         "x" :d2,
         "y" :2d
     } }
    .....
    .....]
```

Here both the data from x.csv and y.csv will be in the json data with two different keys(x represent the data from x.csv and y represent the data from y.csv)but having same column(like B or D).
Can any one share the script.
I tried but How can I take the column name dynamic.to convert it to json we have to know the column name.But instead of knowing the column name prior I have to make it dynamic so that for any csv file, to convert the data to json we don't need to mention the column.It can be taken automatically from csv's column name

Comment: file1 = "/home/arup/Desktop/MergePoc/1/eogcompletions.csv"
output = "/home/arup/Desktop/MergePoc/1/eogcompletions.json"
f = open(file1, 'r')
    csv_reader = csv.DictReader(f)
    
    
    jsonf = open(output,'w') 
    data = json.dumps([r for r in csv_reader])
    jsonf.write(data) 
    f.close()
    jsonf.close()

Comment: Thw above script create a csv file to json having column name as key and data as value.But I cant not make the data using the other csv for same data sctructure